# How to extract descriptor values correctly from positive images with HOG? OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, svm, libsvm, opencv3.0

I have extracted descriptor values from positive and negative training set. For positive images, I have cropped objects from positive images, and only extracted descriptor values from them, not from whole images (Which I am not sure whether I am doing it right).

HOG parameters:

```
HOGDescriptor hog(Size(128,128), Size(8,8), Size(4,4), Size(4,4), 9);
```

Then I have trained SVM using these descriptor values and tested it.

```
Accuracy:    0.69 (TruePositive + TrueNegative/Positive + Negative)
Sensitivity: 0.31 (TruePositive/Positive)
Specificity: 0.93 (TrueNegative/Negative)
```

Sensitivity is very low compared to specificity. I am getting similar sensitivity when I use the training images for testing (whole images, not cropped ones), which is odd.

What am I doing wrong for extracting descriptor values?

Comment: What is your training size? How many positive and how many negative images do you have? Is it convenient to show some of your data here? The point I'm trying to get at is that it may not (entirely) be a problem of features. It is difficult to tell unless you provide more info on your data. Also, it is probably more suitable for you to post this on [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @lightalchemist Thank you for your comment.
I have got training data from http://www.emt.tugraz.at/~pinz/data/GRAZ_02/. These are roughly 300 positive and 380 negative images.